# chrome browser loads CSS resource in corrupted format during page load for first time

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jsf-2.2

I am dealing with a strange issue only in the Chrome browser (version higher than 100). One of our customers reported that our JSF application screens were not loading properly (without CSS), but worked on subsequent page load or page refresh.

When we try to replicate the scenario, we find that the CSS associated with the screen is not rendered or loaded properly. This occurs infrequently in our development environment but frequently in client environments.

I further analysed the issue via the Chrome Dev tool and found that the CSS file was loaded in a corrupted format (screen attached). This issue is no longer replicable once the page is refreshed. resource is loaded correctly.

I have tried the following.

1.Clear the cookies and caches.
2. Reset chrome browser.
3. I tried to replicate it on different laptops and different versions of the Chrome browser.

I have no idea why this happens or how to resolve this type of problem. I need your help in identifying the root cause of the issue.

Screen shot: [image: Corrupted resource file]

Comment: Why does your CSS file have a .jsf extension on it? Did you set it up like this on purpose?

Comment: Next time please capture request and response headers as well (via *Network* tab). Most presumably this is content encoding going wrong during conditional requests. This is in turn not a HTML/CSS/JSF problem but a server config problem. This means that you'll also need to tell a bit more about your server and its config.

Comment: @BalusC  Unfotunately this issue is only replicable on customer side. (Capturing Request /Response header is not possible).  Our resources are encoded in "ISO-8859-1" to support german language.

Comment: I was referring to content encoding not character encoding. E.g. GZIP.